React suspense fallback retriggers
I have an image that I take from an API endpoint. For a reason, I'm importing the image component inside a Suspense with a fallback. The problem is that every time a useState or a useEffect is executed, the fallback of the Suspense is shown. Is there any way to prevent the Suspense fallback from being shown after the first render or when the image is cached?
 export async function AvatarIcon({ id }: { id: string }) {
  const avatarIcon = await getAvatarIcon(id)

  return (
    <div className="">
      <Image
        src={`data:image/png;base64, ${avatarIcon}`}
        height={40}
        width={40}
        className="relative z-0 h-full w-16"
        alt="Avatar Icon"
      ></Image>
    </div>
  )
}

The other component where I use Suspense:
<div>
  <Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
    <AvatarIcon id={user.id} />
  </Suspense>
</div>


Are you using React Server components or a framework built on it? Im guessing yes as your example would blow up completely on a client component since components can't be async there.

Yes i'm using nextJs. Is there any other way to make this?

And just making sure,  the file AvatarIcon is in does not do a use client anywhere?

fallback is running because the default value of loading prop is "lazy". from docs

The loading behavior of the image. Defaults to lazy.
When lazy, defer loading the image until it reaches a calculated
distance from the viewport.
When eager, load the image immediately.

if you change the loading="eager", this might work (I di not test it out) because the component is already loaded and ready to render.  The Suspense component only shows its fallback content when the wrapped component is not ready to be rendered
But I think that setting an "eager" option inside Suspense doesn't make sense because Suspense is specifically designed to handle components that load asynchronously.

since you are fetching the image, maybe you should be caching this fetch with useSwr or with unstable_cache

since you get the image from api, next.js has loader file option. for example, for cloudinary
// Demo: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_300,c_limit,q_auto/turtles.jpg
export default function cloudinaryLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
const params = ['f_auto', 'c_limit', w_${width}, q_${quality || 'auto'}]
return https://example.com/${params.join(',')}${src}
}


in this loader file, you can confire Caching Behavior :

The following describes the caching algorithm for the default loader.
For all other loaders, please refer to your cloud provider's
documentation.
Images are optimized dynamically upon request and stored in the
/cache/images directory. The optimized image file will be
served for subsequent requests until the expiration is reached. When a
request is made that matches a cached but expired file, the expired
image is served stale immediately. Then the image is optimized again
in the background (also called revalidation) and saved to the cache
with the new expiration date.
The cache status of an image can be determined by reading the value of
the x-nextjs-cache response header. The possible values are the
following:

MISS - the path is not in the cache (occurs at most once, on the first visit)
STALE - the path is in the cache but exceeded the revalidate time so it will be updated in the background
HIT - the path is in the cache and has not exceeded the revalidate time The expiration (or rather Max Age) is defined by either the
minimumCacheTTL configuration or the upstream image Cache-Control
header, whichever is larger. Specifically, the max-age value of the
Cache-Control header is used. If both s-maxage and max-age are found,
then s-maxage is preferred. The max-age is also passed-through to any
downstream clients including CDNs and browsers.

You can configure minimumCacheTTL to increase the cache duration
when the upstream image does not include Cache-Control header or the
value is very low. You can configure deviceSizes and imageSizes to
reduce the total number of possible generated images. You can
configure formats to disable multiple formats in favor of a single
image format.


Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. The eager option and the unstable cache did not work. However, useSwr does the job. Everything works properly now.

const fetcher = (url: string, id: string) => {
  const urlWithQuery = ${url}/${id}/icon
  return fetch(urlWithQuery).then((res) => res.json())
}

const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
  ['/api/avatar', id],
  ([url, id]) => fetcher(url, id),
  {
    revalidateOnFocus: true
  }
)

